# Setting up SSH Password

Tags: ssh, openssh, sshd

I've been setting up ssh access to my desktop computer.
I'm running a Debian Distro.

I've enabled password authentication in the sshd_config file, and I've tried looking for the "keyboard-interactive" config setting, but haven't had any luck.

When I try accessing it via connectbot on my phone, I'm met with the following error:

"Authentication method 'keyboard-interactive' failed."

I've tried to log in with the password associated with my normal user account, as well as the one associated with the root account. Neither have worked.

Is there a default password, or any way to view or modify the password while I'm physically at the desktop computer itself?

Also, are there any configurations I may have missed in terms of hostkeys/authkeys or other settings that may be behind this issue?

EDITS:

Listed "Authentications That Can Continue" are:
publickey, password, keyboard-interactive.

When attempting connection from connectbot on my phone, a keyboard is made available.

I have "usePAM" set to "yes"

I could not find "`ChallengeResponseAuthentication`" in /etc/sshd_config, but as recommended, have enabled "`KbdInteractiveAuthentication`".

I retried the sugested "`ssh -i /dev/null -av localhost`" not long before this round of edits. Upon entering the password, I was met with "Connection Closed by ::11 Port 22".

Comment: Do you have "UsePAM yes" in /etc/ssh/sshd_config?

Comment: Yes, that's enabled

Comment: Can you login **using a password** if you say `ssh -i /dev/null -a -v localhost` from your debian box?  Did you see a line `debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password` just before it prompted you for a password?

Comment: ATCC: publickey, password, and keyboard-interactive

Comment: "accessing it via connectbot on my phone" - does connectbot open a keyboard on your phone? Years of experience with `ssh` lead me to suggest using Public Key Encryption keys, rather than passwords. Read `man ssh-add ssh-keygen ssh-copy-id`. Please [edit] your post to  new information, properly formatted. Information added via comments is hard for you to format, hard for us to read and ignored by future readers (who have better answers).

Comment: Look for `ChallengeResponseAuthentication` or `KbdInteractiveAuthentication` and set it for yes.